# How to join columns from one table to another in Bigquery using Apache beam (Python) for a dataflow

Tags: python, join, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I have two tables stored in Bigquery, and want to join the columns from the one table to another table. This needs to be done using Apache Beam (Python) for a dataflow pipeline in Google cloud platform. Just cannot find an approach to do this with Apache Beam. WriteToBigQuery only appends rows, which is not what I need - need to add columns from another table. Both tables uses the same primary keys. Any help will be appraciated.

FEEDBACK: See responses below from Guillaume. This solved my problem and were a better approach as apposed to using Apache beam and dataflow!

Comment: Why not a simple SQL query? What's the meaning of Dataflow in that context?

Comment: I made use of a SQL query in code which I ran locally, using UPDATE to join the column. But cannot find a good example on how to call an Apache Beam function which allows making changes to an existing table. Only finding options to read the data.
The dataflow needs to get data from NASA POWER (daily and monthly weather data) and append/join the columns to already existing tables in bigquery.

Comment: You want to update the result in a third table?  Why not using merge statement in BigQuery? I still don't see why to use Beam here.

Comment: I'm completely new to gcp, so learning a lot atm. Were mostly told by other people this is the best approach, but any other suggestions are welcome. I do have a python script which makes use of the bigquery and storage modules for gcp, which I ran locally on my machine to download the first 39 years of the data and store/join/append the results in bigquery on gcp. This works perfect, but I could only run it locally. If there is a way to get this code to auto run on a schedule in gcp then that will help a lot, but been told to do this using a Apache beam dataflow in gcp.

Comment: Not a third table. An already existing table. Basically I get the data from NASA POWER (https://power.larc.nasa.gov/docs/), then do some transformations to the data, store it as a table in Bigquery table, and then want to join those new fields to the already existing table. This needs to be done on a daily basis, as its weather data. This is also why I've been told its best to use an Apache beam dataflow. btw, gcp is what the client wants us to use.

Comment: Apologies if my explanation on why we need to use dataflow is unclear. Data needs to be pulled from a site on a daily basis, transformed and loaded into bigquery. Pulling the data from the weather site and doing the transformations on a daily basis works perfect. The transformed data's columns then needs to appended/joined to the bigquery table which stores the daily weather data - this is the step which I'm having trouble with.
All of this needs to be automated. All of this needs to happen on a daily basis without any manual intervention (e.g. manually doing a sql query in bigquery).

Comment: How long take the pulling?

Comment: Very quick (usually about a minute, won't take longer than 3 minutes).

Comment: So, my recommendation is to perform the pulling with Cloud Functions or Cloud Run, and put the result in bigQuery. Then perform a merge query with BigQuery. Dataflow is great and powerful, but when your only destination is bigQuery, start by putting all in BigQuery and then work with SQL. (Faster, stronger, cheaper)

Answer (score 0):

You can try following snippet, to read data from Bigquery over Dataflow and join 2 tables and write data to a new Bigquery table:-

```
    data_loading = (
        p1
        | 'ReadBQ' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query='''SELECT a.Coll1, b.Coll2 FROM `PROJ.dataset.table-a` as a, `PROJ.dataset.table-b` as b WHERE a.coll-join=b.coll-join; ''', use_standard_sql=True))
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Also thought about doing this, but want to avoid creating new tables over and over. The existing table stores daily weather data from NASA POWER, and when a new day's data is available it should append the new data as a column. Used a query to accomplish with some code I ran locally. So if there is a way to do an UPDATE query using Apache Beam it will work, but I only keep finding options using BigQuerySource, which is only for reading data from Bigquery.

Comment: If you want to append a new column then one way is through BQ Stored Procedure. Write a BQ-SP and it will take input Column name that need to be appended and it will return a dummy record as a output to Dataflow pipeline. Coll that stored procedure through ```beam.io.Read```

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at this, Did not know you can call a query stored in BigQuery using beam, so haven't tried this yet. Still completely noob to gcp.